# Forking a 3 phase 380V line into three 220V single phase?

Tags: power-supply, step-down

I need to feed several loads with single phase 220V AC, namely:

- Four 60V DC transformers rated 350W 5.9 amps.
- One VFD transformer connected to a 8 amps motor.

Could I connect everything over a 3 phase 380V line (5 wires 2.5mm each, 3x16amps fused)? I was thinking about forking two phase to the four 350W transformers (2x2) and use the third for the VFD, each branch closed through the neutral. But I am not sure if the single neutral can hold everything.

Comment: (1) By "DC transformers" (which don't exist) do you mean "AC/DC power supplies"? (2) By "VFD transformer" do you mean "VFD" as in "variable frequency drive"?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is four AC/DC power supply units and a variable frequency drive, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Q5ZS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The connection scheme - five single-phase loads on a three-phase supply.*

What you are proposing is normal practice. Most single-phase circuits are just one of a three-phase supply with return on the neutral.

Ideally we try to balance the loads on all three phases but there is no way to do this with your setup. It will be particularly unbalanced if the VFD switches on and off while the PSUs are all on.

> Could I connect everything over a 3 phase 380 V line (5 wires 2.5mm each, 3 × 16amps fused)?

That sounds OK but you'd need to check the regulations for your country.

> But I am not sure if the single neutral can hold everything.

The neutral only has to carry the difference in the currents. You will be able to find plenty of tutorials on this online.

Comment: Great, thanks! Could you explain shortly what are the practical down side of an unbalanced load? Would it be much better to bring in proper 220V sources?

Comment: As explained, 220 V sources are just the phases of the three-phase supply. The general hope is that after the local supply transformer that the loads will average out amongst all the users connected to it.

Comment: @Aderam so long as all the phases are within the power limit agreed with your supplier, a slight imbalance doesn't matter.